# How to access /edit an HTML element without using ID

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a menu item and I want to change the bg color of the menu item that we click by setting a class to it. is it possible to do that without using an ID reference? eg: if I click on menu 4, the function should set a class to that `li` alone.

```
<ul class="navList">
    <li onclick="setActive();">menu 1</li>
    <li onclick="setActive();">menu 2</li>
    <li onclick="setActive();">menu 3</li>
    <li onclick="setActive();">menu 4</li>
    <li onclick="setActive();">menu 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why aren't you doing it with css?

Comment: @TeymurMardaliyerLennon because when the user clicks on some other menu (after clicking one) the active state should be changed and the active state for the previous one should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the event to ul element and access the target LI using `event.target`

In jQuery however it's simple and can be done as follows:

```
$(".navList").on("click", "li", function () {
    $(".navList li").removeClass("bgColor");
    $(this).addClass("bgColor");
});
```

Checkout the jsFiddle links below for both jQuery and non-jquery implementation:

Non-jquery version (vanilla js):
https://jsfiddle.net/bkf8k4fq/1/

jQuery version:
https://jsfiddle.net/bkf8k4fq/2/

Answer (score 1):

Pass `this` (Which refers to the current element) into your `setActive` function. From there, you can use the reference in your function to set the background color (Now known as `obj`):

```
function setActive(obj) {
    obj.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
}
```

The li:

```
<li onclick="setActive(this);">menu 1</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check snippet

```js
function setActive (obj) {
    obj.style.background="red";
}
```

```html
<ul class="navList">
  <li onclick="setActive(this);">menu 1</li>
  <li onclick="setActive(this);">menu 2</li>
  <li onclick="setActive(this);">menu 3</li>
  <li onclick="setActive(this);">menu 4</li>
  <li onclick="setActive(this);">menu 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many possibilities, I demonstrate a hand full:

```js
// you used onclick attribute - which is bad practice for js and messes up the html part, better go for:
document.getElementById("l").addEventListener(
  "click", function() {
    clickCalledFunction(this);
  }
);

function clickCalledFunction(t) {
  event.preventDefault();//don't do return false but prevent the link following href

  var tag=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  alert("byTagName: " + tag + " " + tag[0].innerHTML );
  tag[0].textContent="counting: 1";//textContent will be updated late 
  
  var c=document.getElementsByClassName("link");
  alert("byClassName: " + c[0].innerHTML );
  //c[0].textContent="counting: 2";
  
  var name=document.getElementsByName("anchor");
  alert("byName: " + name[0]);
  //name[0].textContent="counting: 3";
  
  alert("byEventMember: " + t.innerHTML )
  
  alert(t.href);
  // now do the link yourself maybe:
  //window.location.href=t.href;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="l" class="link" name="anchor">cleck me</a>
```